# Add eventbrite gem to my ruby on rails website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, model-view-controller, rubygems, eventbrite

I am trying to list the upcoming events in my city by using eventbrite app on my ruby on rails website 
https://github.com/envoy/eventbrite

What I did is

in my gemfile

```
gem 'eventbrite'
```

in my controller

```
  def blogs
    Eventbrite.token = "AIURA4Q6XH4KXXXMURUD"
    Eventbrite::Category.all
    Eventbrite::Subcategory.all
    Eventbrite::Format.all
  end
```

What should I add in the view file in blog.html.erb to show all the event in a nice way like this website https://www.thenewparish.com/

I tried this `<%= Eventbrite::Category.all %>`

and it gave me

```
{ "locale": "en_US", "pagination": {"object_count":21,"page_number":1,"page_size":50,"page_count":1,"has_more_items":false}, "categories": [ {"id":"103","resource_uri":"https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/categories/103/","name":"Music","name_localized":"Music","short_name":"Music","short_name_localized":"Music"}, {"id":"101","resource_uri":"https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/categories/101/","name":"Business & Professional","name_localized":"Business & Professional","short_name":"Business","short_name_localized":"Business"}, {"id":"110","resource_uri":"https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/categories/110/","name":"Food & Drink","name_localized":"Food & Drink","short_name":"Food & Drink","short_name_localized":"Food & Drink"}, {"id":"113","resource_uri":"https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/categories/113/","name":"Community & Culture","name_localized":"Community & Culture","short_name":"Community","short_name_localized":"Community"}, {"id":"105","resource_uri":"https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/categories/105/","name":"Performing & Visual Arts","name_localized":"Performing & Visual Arts","short_name":"Arts","short_name_localized":"Arts"}, {"id":"104","resource_uri":"https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/categories/104/","name":"Film, Media & Entertainment","name_localized":"Film, Media & Entertainment","short_name":"Film & Media","short_name_localized":"Film & Media"}, {"id":"108","resource_uri":"https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/categories/108/","name":"Sports & Fitness","name_localized":"Sports & Fitness","short_name":"Sports & Fitness","short_name_localized":"Sports & Fitness"}, {"id":"107","resource_uri":"https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/categories/107/","name":"Health & Wellness","name_localized":"Health & Wellness","short_name":"Health","short_name_localized":"Health"}, {"id":"102","resource_uri":"https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/categories/102/","name":"Science & Technology","name_localized":"Science & Technology","short_name":"Science & Tech","short_name_localized":"Science & Tech"}, {"id":"109","resource_uri":"https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/categories/109/","name":"Travel & Outdoor","name_localized":"Travel & Outdoor","short_name":"Travel & Outdoor","short_name_localized":"Travel & Outdoor"}, {"id":"111","resource_uri":"https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/categories/111/","name":"Charity & Causes","name_localized":"Charity & Causes","short_name":"Charity & Causes","short_name_localized":"Charity & Causes"}, {"id":"114","resource_uri":"https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/categories/114/","name":"Religion & Spirituality","name_localized":"Religion & Spirituality","short_name":"Spirituality","short_name_localized":"Spirituality"}, {"id":"115","resource_uri":"https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/categories/115/","name":"Family & Education","name_localized":"Family & Education","short_name":"Family & Education","short_name_localized":"Family & Education"}, {"id":"116","resource_uri":"https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/categories/116/","name":"Seasonal & Holiday","name_localized":"Seasonal & Holiday","short_name":"Holiday","short_name_localized":"Holiday"}, {"id":"112","resource_uri":"https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/categories/112/","name":"Government & Politics","name_localized":"Government & Politics","short_name":"Government","short_name_localized":"Government"}, {"id":"106","resource_uri":"https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/categories/106/","name":"Fashion & Beauty","name_localized":"Fashion & Beauty","short_name":"Fashion","short_name_localized":"Fashion"}, {"id":"117","resource_uri":"https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/categories/117/","name":"Home & Lifestyle","name_localized":"Home & Lifestyle","short_name":"Home & Lifestyle","short_name_localized":"Home & Lifestyle"}, {"id":"118","resource_uri":"https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/categories/118/","name":"Auto, Boat & Air","name_localized":"Auto, Boat & Air","short_name":"Auto, Boat & Air","short_name_localized":"Auto, Boat & Air"}, {"id":"119","resource_uri":"https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/categories/119/","name":"Hobbies & Special Interest","name_localized":"Hobbies & Special Interest","short_name":"Hobbies","short_name_localized":"Hobbies"}, {"id":"199","resource_uri":"https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/categories/199/","name":"Other","name_localized":"Other","short_name":"Other","short_name_localized":"Other"},
```

Comment: The response return is in `Hash` format. You need to understand the fundamentals. Checkout https://github.com/BurdetteLamar/AboutRuby/blob/master/core/Hash/about/markdown.md and then you will learn how to iterate and read values from `Hash`

Comment: @AmitPatel Thank you for the link :) I will check it but can you help me what to write in my view file?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Way to Get the Data from the Response 
Showing all the Category Data here is sample code

```
<% response_hash = Eventbrite::Category.all %>

<% response_hash[:categories].each do |category|%>
  <%= category[:resource_uri]%>
  <%= category[:name]%>
  <%= category[:name_localized]%>
  <%= category[:short_name]%>
  <%= category[:short_name_localized]%>
<% end %>
```

For the Pagination details also get the object

`{:object_count=>21, :page_number=>1, :page_size=>50, :page_count=>1, :has_more_items=>false}`

So, you can get the Total no of record and page no by this

```
<%= response_hash[:pagination][:object_count] %>
<%= response_hash[:pagination][:page_number] %>
```

More details of the response and input, you can visit this Site

I'll recommend using this site and call the direct API for get and show the data instead of the gem in this way you will learn more and have more control over data.

For more details on how to call and what params to pass you can visit this detailed documentation
https://www.eventbrite.com/platform/docs/events

Comment: Thank you! I got this https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/categories/103/ Music Music Music Music https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/categories/101/ Business & Professional Business & Professional Business Business... how can I make it look like this https://www.thenewparish.com/

Comment: @nourza I'm not able to access the links you shared I'm getting `401 UNAUTHORIZED`

Comment: You can check the result here http://www.limoexotic.com/blogs

Comment: as per my understanding, you want to get all the events to belong to your city and show up on your site. for that, you need to use the different approach not as u used above.

Comment: as per your above approach, you are getting all the
 Event Category and then you have to get the all event belong to those event categories. 
`EventCtegory -> get the Event.`
But you have to change the approch for get the events of your city
You can use this option for get the event of your city 

```all_events = Eventbrite::Event.search({q: 'Your City Name'})```
then loop over to this and get all the events data from the hash and show it to your site.

Comment: @nourza For more details on how to call and what params to pass you can visit this detailed documentation
https://www.eventbrite.com/platform/docs/events

Comment: Thank you Hafiz. unable to find any endpoint with location.
Do you know what the venue id of Vancouver city?